# XSP.partialRefresh does not fire after XSP.confirm

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Short overview of my issue: I have a large form with several fields, one of them is a `xe:djFilteringSelect` and one a `xp:combobox`. The `xp:combobox` is computet depending on the value selected in the filtering select. Now my customers want that if they change the value of the filtering select of a already saved docoument they should be prompted with a warning. So i want to add a confirm message to the onChange event of the `djfiltering`select to cancel it's SSJS code wich changes the combobox.

Prompting the user with a confirm ("change value?...") box is no big deal but reseting the value back (on ClientSide) if the users selects "no" gives me a lot of trouble.

What i have already tryed:

If i use a **simple confirm** action all further onChange actions get canceled but the `djFilteringSelect` field keeps it's user selected value. So if i fire a partial refresh on the filtering select the original value form the document is displayed but i don't know where to add it because there is no onCancel or did i miss something here?

I also tried it from the CSJS with **window.confirm** and **XSP.confirm** and reset the value manual with a XSP.partialrefreshGet() if the user selects 'no' but in this case the partial refresh does not work:

```
if(!XSP.confirm("execute?")){                                   
    XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:repeat1}",{
      onStart: function () {console.log("start");},
      onComplete: function () {console.log("finish");},
      onError: function () {console.log("error");}  
         });
    return false;
}
```

If i move the partial refresh to a function and call it from e.g. firebug it works fine but if i call it inside the if(confirm){} it does nothing at all. The return false does work the SSJS does not get executed. The value in the document is not changed (as intended), but the djFilteringSelect keeps the selected value on the ClientSide.

I also tried Mark Leusink´s [dojo-style Confirm](http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/m.leusink/entry/dojo_style_confirm_dialogs_in_xpages?lang=de_de) but same Problem with the partial refresh here.

If i set the value back manual instead of using a partial refresh with dijit.byId(item).setValue it will resoult in another onChange Event... loop. **Update:** If i use dijit.byId(item).set("value",newVal,false) the onChange does not fire direct it changes the value as intended but then the onChange fires when the filtering select looses ist ??focus!?!? ...

So my questions:

1. Is there a ways to execute any Code after the confirm action if the user selects "no".
2. Why is the partial refresh in my CSJS not working (i dont see any traffic in firebug and i dont get any errors not even the onError of the refresh gets fired).
3. Does anyone know a different approach to my problem?

**update**:
My current 'solution' is to use window.location.reload() instead of the XSP.partialRefresh to reload the site. But this solution does not really satisfy me, because in IE the whole page is flickering.. in firfox i can live with it.

Comment: to me your approach looks too complicated to start with: onChange is fired AFTER a different option has been selected, so even if you would succeed you would need to remember the previous selection in order to reset the value. Have you tried to present the confirm BEFORE users can change a value?

Comment: Other fields than the xe:djFilteringSelect reset automatical if you cancel the save Action. the Input behind the filtering select gets also resetted. But the reset gets not shown in the dojo component. If i do a partial refresh after the confirm via another button or firebug it Displays the original value.

Comment: Are testing this using MSIE? That browser doesn't fire its onChange before the item looses focus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994495/submit-search-on-enter-not-working-in-ie?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I am testing in IE and Firefox.. the onchange fires correct but the XSP.partialRefresh in it does not get executed... i dont even see a GET in the firebug.